# Trouble implementing the next-auth (app-index.js:32 [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR])

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm new in next auth. I'm trying to implement next-auth credential.

This is my option

```
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Username:",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "your-cool-username",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password:",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "your-awesome-password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { username, password } = credentials as any;
        try {
          const res = await fetch("http://192.168.20.89:48000/v1/auth/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username,
              password,
            }),
          });

          const user = await res.json();
          if (res.ok && user) {
            return user;
          } else return null;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
```

My env:

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=Z9KQ******************ABC=
```

I also wrapped my `sessionProviders`:

```
'use client'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

export default function AuthProvider({ children }: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    return (
        <SessionProvider>
            {children}
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}
```

My wrappers:

```
const LayoutWrapper: FC<ChildrenProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const emotionCache = createEmotionCache();

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
        <Theme>
          <StateProvider>
            {children}
          </StateProvider>
        </Theme>
      </CacheProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

```
const RootLayout: FC<ChildrenProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <LayoutWrapper>
      <html lang="en" dir="rtl">
        <body cz-shortcut-listen="false">
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </LayoutWrapper>
  );
};
```

The error I'm getting is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MtZa.png)

Can you provide a solution?

I didn't even try to sign it in from login components, but the error occurred